# Java glob find files

Tags: java, glob

I have two files - abc.txt and abx.xls in C:\Test. I was checking how to use glob like syntax with Java and came across [below](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) code:

```
/**
 * Sample code that finds files that match the specified glob pattern.
 * For more information on what constitutes a glob pattern, see
 * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob
 *
 * The file or directories that match the pattern are printed to
 * standard out.  The number of matches is also printed.
 *
 * When executing this application, you must put the glob pattern
 * in quotes, so the shell will not expand any wild cards:
 *              java Find . -name "*.java"
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitOption.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Find {

    public static class Finder
        extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final PathMatcher matcher;
        private int numMatches = 0;

        Finder(String pattern) {
            matcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                    .getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
        }

        // Compares the glob pattern against
        // the file or directory name.
        void find(Path file) {
            Path name = file.getFileName();
            if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
                numMatches++;
                System.out.println(file);
            }
        }

        // Prints the total number of
        // matches to standard out.
        void done() {
            System.out.println("Matched: "
                + numMatches);
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each file.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(file);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each directory.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(dir);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file,
                IOException exc) {
            System.err.println(exc);
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    static void usage() {
        System.err.println("java Find <path>" +
            " -name \"<glob_pattern>\"");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {

        if (args.length < 3 || !args[1].equals("-name"))
            usage();

        Path startingDir = Paths.get(args[0]);
        String pattern = args[2];

        Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
        Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
        finder.done();
    }
}
```

I then execute it with following command:

```
% java Find "C:\Test" -name "*.*"
```

It gives me the output

> Matched: 0

I then wrote a simple code as below:

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.*");
File pollDirectoryFile = new File("C:\\Test");
File[] files = pollDirectoryFile.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files);
for (File file : files) {
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(file.getName());
        if (matcher.matches(path)) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
}
```

Interestingly, when it is ran, it gives me the expected output

> abc.txt
>
> abc.xls

Can someone please guide what is the difference? I am using JDK7u25 on Windows7.

EDIT: when I actually run it from command-line it gave me the correct output. It doesn't work however when I run it from my eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the program you came across doesn't check the command line properly. It is expecting '-name' for arg[1] but with the usage suggests that it is actually in arg[2]. Use a debugger to check this yourself.

It's a simple fix, which I will leave for you to figure out.

Comment: No. It is correct. args[0] = "C:\Test" args[1]= "-name" args[2]="*.*. Ok but interestingly, when I actually run it from command-line it gave me the correct output now. It doesn't work however when I run it from my eclipse project.

Comment: @ParagJ If it doesn't work when you run it from eclipse then you should add that information to the question.

Comment: My mistake, I took Find to be an argument too. In eclipse I imported the whole thing and can see that the \*.\* is being expanded to represent all files in the current directory, even when quoted - and returns a matched count of zero.

Comment: @DaveRlz: Exactly, I am facing the same issue. What is the reason?